# android phone number returned as data1

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-cursor

I am trying to use the following code to read a phone number. But it ever returns the number as `data1`. How do I fix this to get the actual number?

```
minorCursor = contentResolver.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE },
                    " DISPLAY_NAME = '" + name + "'", null, null);
                while (minorCursor.moveToNext()) {

                    switch (minorCursor.getInt(minorCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE))) {
                    case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                        phoneNumber = Phone.NUMBER;
                        break;
                    case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                        phoneNumber = Phone.NUMBER;
                        break;
                    case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                        phoneNumber = Phone.NUMBER;
                        break;
                    case Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
                        phoneNumber = Phone.NUMBER;
                        break;
                    }
}
```

I got the code from the third response to [How to retrieve Contact name and phone number in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613104/how-to-retrieve-contact-name-and-phone-number-in-android) because I assume he is saying that the methods used by the other replies have been deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

get your phone number like this.

```
String phoneNumber = minorCursor.getString(minorCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
```

You need to get phone number from `cursor` returned above `query`.

What you are trying to do is just getting the `constant` value in `Phone` class

i.e `Phone.NUMBER` is constant field in `Phone` class, it will not give you phone number