# How to get a list of locally stored phone contacts with App Inventor 2?

Tags: android, app-inventor

So wasn't sure how to title this one but I'm hoping someone with Android experience can answer this for me.

I'm trying to turn Android code into **App Inventor 2** code. I need to start a new activity and have the relevant Action, ActivityPackage, ActivityClass, DataType, ExtraKey, ExtraValue (whether all of these are needed for this specific situation I'm not sure) to input into **an ActivityStarter that views the locally stored phone contacts**.

I am sure there is a way, there is in just Android app making with Java but I need help translating that code across. I'm pretty sure I want an `android.intent.action.VIEW` and `contactsContract.CommonDataKindsPhone` I'm just not sure in which parts in should go and what else I need to than be able to add that information to a list.

This is what I have so far:

[image]

I'm sure others would appreciate this information, as well as how to get other related data to contacts into App Inventor 2.

Also I know about `ContactPicker.PhoneNumberList` and `PhoneNumberPicker.PhoneNumberList` neither of which are able to find any contacts on my phone which is why I'm trying to work out a work-around.

Anyway any help is appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unfortunately it's not possible to get a list of locally stored phone contacts with App Inventor**. See also [issue 734](https://code.google.com/p/app-inventor-for-android/issues/detail?id=734) in the Issues List. I suggest you to star this issue, so probably one day we get this feature into App Inventor.

The `ContactPicker.PhoneNumberList` or `PhoneNumberPicker.PhoneNumberList` only give you all phone numbers of a contact after picking a contact.

App Inventor has its limitations and unfortunately you can't do something like this as described in this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613104/how-to-retrieve-contact-name-and-phone-number-in-android). The only thing you can do is to access the [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference) with the `web` component to get a list of contacts, but precondition is, your contacts are synchronized with Google, but this is not what you want. An example to do that you can find [here](https://puravidaapps.com/contacts.php).