# ContactsContract is not returning Phone Number but Name

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I have used this code to display the name and the phone number of my phone even though it is returning the name only, I would appreciate any answer. does it also works if i have google account synced?

CODE:
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (people != null && people.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            try {
                int nameFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
                String contact = people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
                Log.d("CONTACT: ", contact);
                int numberFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER);
                String number = people.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex);
                Log.d("NUMBER: ", number);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR: ", e.toString());
            }

        } while (people.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

ERROR:

```
  04-16 05:16:27.839    1426-1426/com.chatter.contactsaccess D/CONTACT:﹕ Test
04-16 05:16:27.839    1426-1426/com.chatter.contactsaccess D/NUMBER:﹕ 1
```

EDITED

Comment: use cursor like this, first a if condition and then do-while loop
if (people != null && people.moveToFirst()){ do{  //your code  }while(people.moveToNext() }

Comment: The output is still the same

Comment: so have you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code to get all the phone contacts in your phone.

In onCreate of your Activity pass the intent to open the phone contacts like,

```
private static final int PICK_CONTACT=1;

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

And get the details of the selected contact in onAcivityResult like below

```
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(reqCode==0)return;
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (reqCode) {
            case (PICK_CONTACT) :
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    ContentResolver cr=getActivity().getContentResolver();
                    final Cursor c =  cr.query(contactData, null, null, null, null);

                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        ArrayList<String> alNumbers=new ArrayList<>();


                        String id =c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                        String hasPhone =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                        if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                            Cursor phones = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,
                                    null, null);
                            if(phones.moveToFirst())
                            {
                                while(!phones.isAfterLast())
                                {
                                    cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                    alNumbers.add(cNumber);
                                    phones.moveToNext();
                                }
                            }
                            phones.close();
                            final CharSequence[] items = alNumbers.toArray(new String[alNumbers.size()]);
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                            builder.setTitle("Choose a number");
                            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                                    cNumber = items[item].toString();
                                    name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                    phone.setText(name+" ("+cNumber+")");
                                }
                            });
                            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                            if(alNumbers.size() > 1) {
                                alert.show();



                               }
 name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no

> ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER

present in

> ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI

, use

> ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html

[Try this way,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613104/how-to-retrieve-contact-name-and-phone-number-in-android)

```
String name = c=.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
String phoneNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
```

Comment: It returns 1, but how can i get the number

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613104/how-to-retrieve-contact-name-and-phone-number-in-android

Comment: doesnt seems to work, he is using deprecated methods, with his function the HAST_PHONE... returns 0

Comment: if it returns 0 try clicking on someother number, If it returns 1 then you will get the number, maybe it doesn't have phone number, and no, HAS_PHONE_NUMBER is not deprecated.

Comment: `managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);` is deprecated, and I just created 1 person with number.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` for `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI`

the snipped code is the following (I just want to get the name and phone in string):

```
Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        while(people.moveToNext()) {
            int nameFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
            String contact = people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
            int numberFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            String number = people.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex);
            Log.e("CONTACT: ", contact + " " + number);
        }

        people.close();
```